# Getting an error while loading data with DMS from mongodb to elasticsearch, any ideas?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-dms

I am trying to use AWS DMS and transfer data from mongodb to amazon elasticsearch.

i am encountering the following log in CloudWatch.

```
{
   "error": {
       "root_cause": [
           {
               "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
               "reason": "Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters."
           }
       ],
       "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
       "reason": "Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters."
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

This is my configuration for the mongo db source.
it has the `_id as a separete column` check box enabled.
i tried disabling it and it says that there is no primary key.
is there anything that you guys know that can fix it ?

quick note:
i have added mapping of the _id field to `old_id` and now it doesn't import all the other field, even when i add them in the mapping

Answer (score 0):

As ElasticSearch will not support the LOB data type, Other fields are not migrated.

Add additional transformation rule to change the data type to String

```
{
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "3",
      "rule-name": "3",
      "rule-action": "change-data-type",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "test",
        "table-name": "%",
        "column-name": "%"
      },
      "data-type": {
        "type": "string",
        "length": "30"
      }
}
```